# Converting recursive function with more calls to iterative function java

Tags: java, recursion

Is there a way to convert this recursive algorithm to iterative without using stacks?

```
public static float T1(int n, float y) {
    if (n == 0)
        return y;
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;

    return 2 * y * T1(n - 1, y) - T1(n - 2, y);
}
```

What keeps me confused is having two calls inside the recursion, and I'm not sure how to convert that using loops.

Comment: It looks like it should be perfectly possible with a single loop, keeping track of the result from the last two iterations to calculate the result for the current iteration.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: OK, posting an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do the same calculation with a `for` loop.

```
public static float T1(int n, float y) {
    if (n==0) return y;
    if (n==1) return 1;
    float p1 = 1, p2 = y; // track the previous two values
    for (int i=2; i <= n; ++i) {
        float p = 2*y*p1 - p2; // calculate the result for this iteration
        p2 = p1; // update the previous values to be used in the next iteration
        p1 = p;
    }
    return p1;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to do something with a while loop but wasn't really successful. Thing that confused me the most is two recursive calls. Thanks for clearing this up!